# How to prevent devs to download lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have some lambda functions and I usually grant access to thirds devs to my AWS account.

They eventually can request my lambda functions for working or testing purposes but I want to prevent them to download the source code.

Is there a way to manage who can download (or not) my lambda files ?

Comment: You can limit their Lambda permissions. Presumably they assume some IAM role in your account, or are given IAM users in your account. If all they should be able to do is invoke these Lambdas then only give them `lambda:InvokeFunction` on the relevant function ARNs.

Answer (score 1):

This will come down to the specifics of how they test the lambda; specially, how your lambda is configured and the users access permissions. Typically there is 3 scenarios that could play out here:

1. If you have a **non-zipped** lambda and the IAM user is **granted console management access** then the answer is no. There is **no method to prevent** them copying the code.
2. If you have a **non-zipped** lambda and the user is **only** provided **Cli permissions** then you **can restrict** their right on IAM to prevent getting the source code.
3. If you have a **zipped** lambda and save the source code resides in S3, then you **can restrict** IAM permissions on the user to prevent downloading the lambda code. This applies to **both** Users with **Console Management access** and/or **Cli access**.

*Note: General rule of thumb here is if they can see the code they can copy it. Which means it will be awfully hard for them to 'test' the code. If they are a 3rd party, you're much better putting in place a contractual agreement to prevent them retaining any copy of the code beyond the purposes of the project*

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you know if they(3rd party who test features) have retained that piece of code or if they are using in some other project?

Comment: What do you mean by zipped and non-zipped lambda ? I think when we upload a function to lambda, anyway the file has to be a .zip . So my code are always zipped before it gets to lambda.

Comment: I have no way to know if someone retained a piece of my code this is why I am looking for a strategy to manage who can access or not the source code of my lambda functions.

Comment: Uploading a zip file for your lambda is not a requirement. You can add the code directly to the service through a variety of different options (including CLI). 

Also, aside from restricting permissions to view the code you can not prevent it (that was my main point). If you wanted to know if someone 'downloaded your code' you could potentially find reference in the CloudTrail logs. However, this would not capture any ctrl + c / ctrl + v actions.

Comment: @Prish There is no way direct way of knowing if it is being used else where once its uncontrolled. However, contractual agreements act as a deterrent and provide a level of security to dissuade the act.