# How to password protect Lambda zip file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working with several devs that have an access to my AWS console and Lambda (full access) . However, I need to restrict access to my lambda source code. In lambda, any devs can download the zip file just by going to `Actions -> export function -> Download deployment package`. So , I need to add a protection layer to these zip files so that only the devs that have the password will be enabled to unzip and access the source code.

Any Idea of how I can process it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability in AWS Lambda to password protect the zip files used for functions.

You would need to **configure their IAM permissions** so that they cannot access the Lambda function, such as adding a `Deny` policy for that function.

Alternatively, you could keep sensitive Lambda functions in a **different AWS account** to which they do not have access, then trigger the Lambda function cross-account.

Comment: I am not so familiar with AWS and I can't figure out how I can deny access to a specific lambda function for a specific user. I don't see this option in the Lambda console.

Comment: As per your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61501258/174777), such permissions would be granted via the IAM policies that grant the Developers access to use AWS services. You say that the Devs have "full access". The first thing to do is _not_ give them full access. Alternatively, add a `Deny` policy that overrides such access. Take a look [Policy Evaluation Logic - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html).

Comment: Okay I will take a glance. Thanks.